# How do create a universal static library in Xcode 4 that exposes functionality directly from other linked libraries

Tags: iphone, xcode4, static-libraries

We have 2 static libraries.  I want o build a 3rd static library that behaves like a wrapper/bridge to the first 2 in Xcode 4.   I also want this to be a universal build as we want to publish our library as an sdk

Scenario is

Library A contains methods.  1 ,2 ,3
Library B contains methods 4,5,6

Library C. Links in library A and B and and has method 7 which use functionality from both library A and B.  It also has needs to expose method 2 directly from library A.

Can we just package library A header or should we write a method which just acts a bridge for library a method 2

Answer (score 1):

Providing a prototype for the methods in library A that you want to expose should be enough —e.g. offering library A's header, as you suggest—.

Comment: I can get the library to build no problems using this layout,  however I'm still getting problems.  When I include this Library C in another project it fails to build because it requires the headers from Library A & B.